# On macOS, how can I intercept calls to dlsym?

Tags: macos, dlopen

I'm trying to inspect the behavior of a program that calls `dlopen` and `dlsym`: the end goal is to interpose a tiny function that logs calls to functions obtained via `dlsym`.

Normally, for some function `foo` that you want to wrap with `DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES`, you write something like this:

```
void (*real_foo)(void);

void init() __attribute__((constructor)) {
    real_foo = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "foo");
}

void foo(void) {
    puts("foo was called");
    real_foo();
}
```

The problem is that when you're trying to wrap `dlsym`, you end up with this:

```
void* (*real_dlsym)(void* handle, const char* symbol);

void init() __attribute__((constructor)) {
    real_dlsym = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "dlsym");
}

void* dlsym(void* handle, const char* symbol) {
    return real_dlsym(handle, symbol);
}
```

`init` ends up calling your own implementation of `dlsym`, which is not helpful.

How can I get the "real" dlsym when I'm exporting a different one? Or is there a better way to intercept calls to dlsym?

Answer (score 0):

At least on a 10.12 system, `dlsym` is actually implemented in `/usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib`. It should work to `dlopen()` that file, then call `dlsym()` with the returned handle to get the real `dlsym()` implementation. You may want extra `mode` flags to `dlopen()`, like `RTLD_FIRST` and/or `RTLD_LOCAL`. Sorta like:

```
    void *libdyld_handle = dlopen("/usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib", RTLD_LAZY);
    void *dlsym_funcptr = dlsym(libdyld_handle, "dlsym");
```

Comment: I can’t use dlsym because it calls my own “implementation” of it. I can’t call it anything else, or else it won’t replace the real dlsym.

Answer (score 0):

*Late answer* ilustrating an interesting quirk of Dyld4 implementation (i.e MacOS 12.x Monterey & iOS15). Essentially the global dyld object leaks its details through a hardware register on `main` startup (regardless of the platform).

Obviously that's a hack, don't ever consider doing this in serious production code.

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
#ifdef __x86_64__
    register void* rbx asm("rbx");  //dyld4::gDyld
    register void* (*typed_dlopen)( void*, char const*, int) asm("rax");
    register void* (*typed_dlsym)(void*, char const*, void*) asm("rcx");

    __asm volatile(".intel_syntax noprefix;"
#if TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR
                   "add rbx,0x100000;"
#endif
                   "mov rax,[rbx];"
                   "mov rcx,[rax + 0x88];"
                   "mov rax,[rax + 0x70];"
                   : "=r"(typed_dlopen), "=r"(rbx), "=r"(typed_dlsym)); //dyld4::gDyld

    void* handle = typed_dlopen(rbx, "libc.dylib", RTLD_NOW);
    int (*myPrintf)(const char * __restrict, ...) = typed_dlsym(rbx, handle, "printf");

    myPrintf("Hello world");
#endif
#if TARGET_CPU_ARM64
    register void* x19 asm("x19");  //dyld4::gDyld
    register void* (*typed_dlopen)( void*, char const*, int) asm("x0");
    register void* (*typed_dlsym)(void*, char const*, void*) asm("x1");

    __asm volatile("ldr x0,[x19] \t\n"
                   "ldr x1,[x0, 0x88]\t\n"
                   "ldr x0,[x0, 0x70]\t\n"
                   : "=r"(typed_dlopen), "=r"(x19), "=r"(typed_dlsym)); //dyld4::gDyld

    void* handle = typed_dlopen(x19, "libc.dylib", RTLD_NOW);
    int (*myPrintf)(const char * __restrict, ...) = typed_dlsym(x19, handle, "printf");

    myPrintf("Hello world");
#endif
    //Rest of your startup code e.g. UIApplicationMain(...) / NSApplicationMain(...)
}
```

Those offsets `0x88`, `0x70` come from original `libdyld.dylib`, and are used in genuine `dlopen` & `dlsym` when interfacing with dyld4 internals. So in a nutshell we're tapping into the internal implementation directly (hence the extra 1st arg being the c++ `this` pointer). Time will tell if they will remain stable for future renditions of Apple operating systems.

This can also be repurposed to use `void __attribute__ ((constructor)) premain(void) {` instead (by using `r15` and `x8` or `x20` respectively).

```
void __attribute__ ((constructor)) premain(void) {
#ifdef __x86_64__
    register void* r15 asm("r15");  //dyld4::gDyld
    register void* (*typed_dlopen)( void*, char const*, int) asm("rax");
    register void* (*typed_dlsym)(void*, char const*, void*) asm("rcx");
    __asm volatile(".intel_syntax noprefix;"
                   "mov rax,[r15];"
                   "mov rcx,[rax + 0x88];"
                   "mov rax,[rax + 0x70];"
                   : "=r"(typed_dlopen), "=r"(r15), "=r"(typed_dlsym)); //dyld4::gDyld
    void* handle = typed_dlopen(r15, "libc.dylib", RTLD_NOW);
    int (*myPrintf)(const char * __restrict, ...) = typed_dlsym(r15, handle, "printf");

    myPrintf("Hello world");
#endif
#if TARGET_CPU_ARM64
    register void* x8 asm("x8");  //dyld4::gDyld
    register void* (*typed_dlopen)( void*, char const*, int) asm("x0");
    register void* (*typed_dlsym)(void*, char const*, void*) asm("x1");

    __asm volatile("ldr x0,[x8] \t\n"
                   "ldr x1,[x0, 0x88]\t\n"
                   "ldr x0,[x0, 0x70]\t\n"
                   : "=r"(typed_dlopen), "=r"(x8), "=r"(typed_dlsym)); //dyld4::gDyld

    void* handle = typed_dlopen(x8, "libc.dylib", RTLD_NOW);
    int (*myPrintf)(const char * __restrict, ...) = typed_dlsym(x8, handle, "printf");

    myPrintf("Hello world");
#endif
}
```

**Simulator update**
Interestingly in the main variant I discovered there are 2 different implementations of `dlopen`:

```
0x000000010e78272a (dyld`dyld4::APIs::dlopen(char const*, int))
0x000000010424b278 (dyld_sim`dyld4::APIs::dlopen(char const*, int))
```

The former would crash when using simulator. But, thanks to another sketchy coincidence premain seems to use another(?) `//dyld4::gDyld`  shifted by offset `0x1000000`. If we shift the `rbx` one in `main` it works.

Hack verified working for:

- MacOS Monterey 12.3.1 , x86-64
- MacOS Monterey 12.4 , x86-64
- MacOS Monterey 12.6 , x86-64
- iOS15.0 iPhone13 Pro
- iOS15.1 iPad
- iOS Simulators x86-64

iOS14.1 used Dyld3 and will crash.
not tested on M1 and its siblings , but in principle they should behave as iOS arms.